# Node.js Mongoose callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, callback, mongoose

I saw a lot of answers but im still unable to make this work.
I have a simple function that i want to return a length of a query find on Mongoose.
It goes like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.user = null
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.locals.user = req.user;
            getMt(req.user.id, function(val) {
                console.log(val) // == 5
                res.locals.mt = val;
            });
        }
        console.log(res.locals.mt); // == undefined
....
}
function getMt(user_id, callback) {
    var Model = require('./models/mt');
    Model.find({'users.user_id': user_id}, 'token', function(err, list) {
        if (err)
            callback(0);
        if (!list)
            callback(0);
        if (list)
            callback(list.length);
    });
}
```

I read a lot about async, and i still cant find a solution for this.
res.locals.mt still shows me undefined after the res.locals.mt = val inside the callback.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exact problem is please define it.

Comment: Sounds like a case for `.count()`?

Comment: In addition to using count(), the second item in your `Model.find()` call should be an object.  Try this for your query:  `Model.find({some:'query'},{token:true},function(err, list){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `next` function!

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.user = null
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.locals.user = req.user;
            getMt(req.user.id, function(val) {
                console.log(val) // == 5
                res.locals.mt = val;
                next(); //<---- add this!!!
            });
        }
....
}
```

Comment: @egnd09 Keep in mind that the `res.locals.mt` will only be set in subsequent `app.get/post/use` call.  In your question example, the `console.log(res.locals.mt)` will only return the value you expect if it is inside the `getMt()` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you where you're trying to go?

```
function getMt(user_id, callback) {
    var Model = require('./models/mt');
    Model.count({'users.user_id': user_id}, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return callback(0);
        }
        callback(count);
    });
}
```

Comment: Its a better approach to the count, but I cant get val to set res.locals.mt, that was my goal. Im sorry i wasnt clear on the question. Gonna edit it.